# Bypass angular 5 HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule when using ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I've followed the Hero tutorial using angular version 5.
All is working well when I just use the frontend but I want to test this with a real server. I've built the app using ng build --prod but it still uses the HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.

How can I bypass HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule in production environment but still use it in development?

This is my imports section in my app.module.tst

```
imports: [
 36     BrowserModule,
 37     AppRoutingModule,
 38     FormsModule,
 39     HttpClientModule,
 40     HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataServiceTodos, { dataEncapsulation: false, pas    sThruUnknownUrl: true })
 41   ],
```

Thanks,

Comment: write your own API's for heroes, update heroes and reomve `InMemory` from your module file

Comment: I'm new to Angular so sorry but what does it mean I need to write my own API? There isn't a flag or something I can tell the Mock mechanism to be turned off on production?

Comment: Obliviously No, because if you disabled this flag is your application will work? No its crashed. And API means to write your own function for handling `heroes` listing and update/add etc

Comment: Crash? Why it would crash? The http requests will go to my real server instead of the mock up.

Answer (score 0):

In NgModule it's necessary to use variable environment. If you want to disable Memory data service this is the code:

```
imports: 
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   FormsModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   !environment.production ?
       HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataServiceTodos, { dataEncapsulation: false, pas    sThruUnknownUrl: true }) : []
  ],
```

https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api